# Ember js #LinkTo tag and its behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, ember.js

I have an issue where, when I click a link from my page(LinkTo), **Ctrl + click**, it opens a new tab, but the controls go to the next tab in chrome, whereas in IE the control stays in the same page. I figured out that `#linkTo` behaviour in chrome is different. Can anyone help?

tried replacing with anchor tag but the routes don't work on single click

`{{#linkTo "routename" "id"}}..{{/linkTo}}`

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, What's your Chrome browser version? Based on your description, I test it on Chrome (version 73.0.3683.103), Edge 42 version and IE 11, when I use ctrl+click click the link, it just opens a new tab and the controls will not go to the next tab.

Comment: Chrome version 73

Comment: What about ctrl + shift + click for Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little while to figure out what you were asking but I think I have figured it out

Firstly I would like to note that this behaviour has got **nothing specifically to do with EmberJS** and is 100% a browser behaviour. You will see this behaviour with any link (regardless if it is using JavaScript) but I will explain more about that below.

So when I tried to recreate your behaviour on Chrome, I didn't see that when I used <kbd>ctrl + click</kbd> to open a new tab it **didn't** switch to that tab automatically. When talking to one of my colleagues about this it seems like there is a setting in Chrome where you can change this behaviour so maybe you have already changed that setting? You can see more discussion on this topic and related issues over on the [Chrome Support Website](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/685410?hl=en).

So I mentioned that this isn't an Ember specific problem, you will experience this with any web page, even if they don't use JavaScript. Interestingly Ember is making it possible for you to open in a new tab in the first place because of its strong focus on the URL  if you inspect the page on your Ember app you will see that it is actually putting a valid `<a href="/something">Your link here</a>` element in the DOM, this means that you will get the nice behaviour in a <kbd>ctrl + click</kbd> instead of just opening a new tab with the homepage of your app.

---

This question was answered as part of "May I Ask a Question" Season 2 Episode 1. If you would like to see us discuss this answer in full you can check out the video here: https://youtu.be/v1rBL5_KPqU

Answer (score 1):

You could also use ember-href-to addons and a handlebars template compiler. I've used the "ember-href-to" plugin and it works well. You can see the daily use of href-to on ember-href-to.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-href-to

ember-href-to: A lightweight alternative to `{{link-to}}`. No components, no class bindings - just a bound anchor href and a click handler.

Every time you use a `{{link-to}}`, you create a view. This is usually fine, but in cases where you're creating many of these, performance can suffer. `{{href-to}}` **simply creates a URL and is 12x faster than** `{{link-to}}`

Check out the branchmark https://github.com/GavinJoyce/ember-performance/pull/1

#### Usage:

```
{{#href-to "routename" "id"}}..{{/href-to}}
```

By using this, you do not need to pass model, because it knows what it is. All you need is the routename.

#### This is an Ember CLI addon, to install:

```
ember install ember-href-to
```

`{{href-to}}` has the same interface as `{{link-to}}`, you can use it to link to static and dynamic routes in your ember application:

#### Usage Instructions:

```
<a href="{{href-to 'index'}}">Go Home</a>
<a href="{{href-to 'contacts.contact' contact}}">View Contact 1</a>
<a href="{{href-to 'contacts.contact' 2}}">View Contact 2</a>
<a href="{{href-to 'contact-us' (query-params section='first')}}">You can also use query params</a>
<a href="{{href-to 'contact-us'}}#first">You can also use fragment identifiers</a>
<a href="{{href-to 'contact-us'}}" data-href-to-ignore>
  If you have a catchall route (this.route('catchall', { path: "/*" })),
  you need to add the attribute "data-href-to-ignore",
  otherwise you will always match it
</a>
```

Comment: No problem! Good quality answer. Here u get my upvote goodman

Answer (score 0):

I think you better take that routing behaviour in to corresponding JS file other than using linkTo helper. Then you have more control into your action and can do different things based on browser being loaded.

Below are high level steps to achieve that.

1. Add "action" helper instead of "linkTo" helper as below.

```html
<div {{action 'routeToPage'}}></div>
```

2. In JS file, capture that action and do the routing after browser check.

```html
actions: {
    routeToPage: function () {
        var route = this.container.lookup('route:application');
        
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") !== -1 ) {
        // Loaded inside Chrome Browser
          route.render(routeString, <your params>);
        }
    }
}
```

I will not going to explain how route.render works in EmberJs here. If you need I can help with that as well. And you can check other browsers as well with navigator.userAgent depends on your requirement.